# How to import an already existing AWS Glue Crawler in Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-glue

I have a module that creates crawlers... and uses this variable to iterate over a map of objects where the crawlers are defined with the details that are needed

```
module main.tf
```

```
resource "aws_glue_crawler" "crawler" {
  for_each = var.crawler_list
  database_name = each.value.database_name
  name          = "${each.value.crawler_name}"
  role          = var.crawler_role_arn
  table_prefix  = each.value.table_prefix

......... and  other elements (the module already correctly displays any crawler...)
```

```
variables.tf
```

```
variable "crawler_list" {
  description = "crawler list"
  type = map(object({
    database_name = string
    crawler_name  = string
    table_prefix  = optional(string, "")
    s3_target = optional(object({
      s3_create_target = optional(bool,false)
      s3_target_path = optional(string, "")
      s3_exclusions  = optional(list(string),[])
    }),{})
    dynamodb_target = optional(object({
      dynamodb_create_target = optional(bool,false)
      dynamodb_target_path = optional(string, "")
    }),{})
    jdbc_target = optional(object({
      jdbc_create_target = optional(bool,false)
      jdbc_connection_name = optional(string, "")
      jdbc_target_path     = optional(string, "")
      jdbc_exclusions      = optional(list(string),[])
    }),{})
  }))
  default = {}
}
```

```
main.tf
```

```
module "crawlers" {
  source = "./modules/crawlers"

  service          = var.service
  crawler_list     = var.crawler_list
  crawler_role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx:role/role-glue"

}
```

```
tfvars
```

```
crawler_list = {
  dynamodb-aud-load-audit = {
    database_name = "dm_web"
    crawler_name  = "dynamodb-aud-load-audit"
    table_prefix  = "vw_"
    dynamodb_target = {
      dynamodb_create_target = true
      dynamodb_target_path   = "vw_dim_geographies"
    }
  }
  dynamodb-vw-dashboard-home = {
    database_name = "dm_web"
    crawler_name  = "dynamodb-vw-dashboard-home"
    dynamodb_target = {
      dynamodb_create_target = true
      dynamodb_target_path   = "vw_dim_geographies"
    }
  }
}
```

At the moment this crawler is deployed with terraform and everything is perfect... now in aws another crawler was created manually with the same configuration and details that are defined in tfvars .. dynamodb-vw-dashboard-home,because the name or the key of the map that you want to access must be indicated when importing and it is the one that I have created in aws but manually.

Now I need to import that crawler to my terraform state.. I have already imported other elements as s3 and it works perfect..I'm following the same strategy

```
command to import
```

```
terraform import -var-file=sanbox.tfvars 'module.crawlers.aws_glue_crawler.crawler["dynamodb-vw-dashboard-home"]' arn:aws:glue:us-east-1:xxxxxxxx:crawler/dynamodb-vw-dashboard-home
```

result

```
terraform import -var-file=sanbox.tfvars 'module.crawlers.aws_glue_crawler.crawler["dynamodb-vw-dashboard-home"]' arn:aws:glue:us-east-1:xxxxxxx:crawler/dynamodb-vw-dashboard-home
module.crawlers.aws_glue_crawler.crawler["dynamodb-vw-dashboard-home"]: Importing from ID "arn:aws:glue:us-east-1:xxxxxx:crawler/dynamodb-vw-dashboard-home"...
data.aws_security_group.lb: Reading...
data.aws_security_group.lc: Reading...
data.aws_security_group.db: Reading...
data.aws_vpc.vpc: Reading...
module.crawlers.aws_glue_crawler.crawler["dynamodb-vw-dashboard-home"]: Import prepared!
  Prepared aws_glue_crawler for import
module.crawlers.aws_glue_crawler.crawler["dynamodb-vw-dashboard-home"]: Refreshing state... [id=arn:aws:glue:us-east-1:398660321297:crawler/dynamodb-vw-dashboard-home]
data.aws_security_group.lc: Read complete after 0s [id=sg-xxxxxxxxx]
data.aws_security_group.lb: Read complete after 0s [id=sg-xxxxxxxxx]
data.aws_security_group.db: Read complete after 0s [id=sg-xxxxxxxxx]
data.aws_vpc.vpc: Read complete after 1s [id=vpc-xxxxxxxxxx]
data.aws_subnets.subnet_apps_ids: Reading...
data.aws_subnets.all: Reading...
data.aws_subnets.subnet_db_ids: Reading...
data.aws_subnets.subnet_publics_ids: Reading...
data.aws_subnets.subnet_apps_ids: Read complete after 0s [id=us-east-1]
data.aws_subnets.all: Read complete after 0s [id=us-east-1]
data.aws_subnets.subnet_publics_ids: Read complete after 0s [id=us-east-1]
data.aws_subnets.subnet_db_ids: Read complete after 0s [id=us-east-1]
╷
│ Error: Cannot import non-existent remote object
│
│ While attempting to import an existing object to
│ "module.crawlers.aws_glue_crawler.crawler[\"dynamodb-vw-dashboard-home\"]", the provider detected that no object       
│ exists with the given id. Only pre-existing objects can be imported; check that the id is correct and that it is       
│ associated with the provider's configured region or endpoint, or use "terraform apply" to create a new remote object   
│ for this resource.
╵
```

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 2):

According to [terraform documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/glue_crawler#import), you have to import Glue crawlers by name and not by ARN:

> Glue Crawlers can be imported using name, e.g.,
>
> `$ terraform import aws_glue_crawler.MyJob MyJob`

So the following should work instead:

```bash
terraform import -var-file=sanbox.tfvars 'module.crawlers.aws_glue_crawler.crawler["dynamodb-vw-dashboard-home"]' dynamodb-vw-dashboard-home
```